# Using javascript get every other Sunday matching a particular week

Tags: javascript

Using `javascript` I need to get the next upcoming date that matches a particular pattern.

The date I need is a Sunday and I can get the next Sunday like this:

```
const date = new Date();
const diff = date.getDay() - 7;
if (diff > 0) {
    date.setDate(date.getDate() + 6);
} else if (diff < 0) {
    date.setDate(date.getDate() + ((-1) * diff));
}
console.log(date);
```

But the Sunday I need to get, is every other Sunday matching the following pattern.

10/20/18
11/03/18
11/17/18
12/01/18
12/15/18

Comment: So what's the problem? Get the first one and keep on adding 14 days.

Comment: But days in your pattern are saturdays...

Answer (score 2):

using momentjs it's easy like this:

```
moment().day(-7) // returns last Sunday
moment().day(0) // returns this Sunday
moment().day(7) // returns next Sunday object
moment().day(14) // returns next+1 Sunday object
```

http://momentjs.com/docs/#/get-set/day/

if you need a JS Date object:

```
moment().day(7).toDate()
```

Comment: I see, understood. But maybe adding a momentjs is not a problem. At least would be good to know how it helps. I hope

Comment: I think it's a grey area. But since there are so many useful libraries out there I think it's helpful to get recommendations. That being said programers in general tend to rely on libraries a bit too much sometimes.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I came up with using just javascript. There is probably a better more efficient way of doing it.

```
function getDateArray(start, end = new Date()) {
  const arr = new Array();
  const sd = new Date(start);
  while (sd <= end) {
    const d = new Date(sd);
    const d2 = new Date(d);
    d2.setDate(d2.getDate() + 13);
    const v = d.valueOf();
    const ds1 = d.toDateString();
    const ds2 = d2.toDateString();
    const obj = { label: `From: ${ds1} To: ${ds2}`, value: v };
    arr.push(obj);
    sd.setDate(sd.getDate() + 14);
  }
  return arr;
}

const today = new Date();
getDateArray('08/19/18', today);
```

I can get the date I need by accessing the last item in the returned array